# Vaadin + Css formatting

Tags: css, spring-boot, gradle, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 14.4.4 with Gradle 6.3 and Spring Boot.

When I was creating a website in developer's mode everything was working well.  Now I switched to productionMode = true and website doesn't load a single css file.

I'm trying to use one css file per class.

After switching back to developer's mode the CSS formatting is not working as it used to.

I tried vaadinClean, vaadinBuildFrontend and vaadinPrepareFrontend but that doesn't seem to fix my problem...

Do you guys have any suggestions does any of you interfered with the same problem as I ?

Comment: How do you reference the CSS files?

Comment: They are all located in "frontend\styles\*.css" and frontend directory is on same level as src java directory.

Also this problem is weird because it was working properly until I tried using productionMode = true.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ..  The theme is compiled on the fly in "development mode", but in "production mode" you need to compile your CSS theme.

Comment: Hello what do you mena by that how can I do such thing ?

Comment: The mean you must compile The Theme or CSS Files by Yourself ...

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how can I do that ??

Comment: just run the class com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler with the SCSS and CSS file names as parameters

Comment: Compiling SCSS files is only a thing in Vaadin 8 and earlier. There's no SCSS to compile in Vaadin 14.

Comment: Are you importing the css files with @CssImport?

Comment: Yes I'm as I've already mentioned it work in developers mode but for some reason when I add dependency productionMode = true in gradle it does not pack CSS with the rest.

Comment: Could you please show us the versions of the vaadin gradle plugin too? I dont think it will work for that Vaadin version, but just to have it asked: are you using PNPM?  Have you tried removing all the generated files (e.g. webpack, packages, ...)?.  Are you using a local node Installation or are you using the ones downloaded by the plugin?

Comment: @cfrick in plugins I have id 'com.vaadin' version '0.14.3.7', and in ext set('vaadinVersion', "14.4.4"). In Gradle I have pnpmEnable = true, Yes I tried removing all generated files before I run the build and css was still messed up and when I replaced with the previous ones it was still not working eventhoug before build it was. I tried both currently I have node installed by myself.

Comment: Just to be sure here: are _all_ styles missing or only the ones you defined for your components? Have you tried without pnpm?

Comment: The styles which I define in fronted/styles/... are missing. Which is bascially every css file.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs of the gradle plugin for
Vaadin](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-gradle-plugin#tasks):

> `./gradlew clean build -Pvaadin.productionMode` - will compile Vaadin
> in production mode, then packages everything into the war/jar archive.
> Automatically calls the `vaadinPrepareFrontend` and
> `vaadinBuildFrontend` tasks.

Note the *explicit* passing of `-Pvaadin.productionMode`.  It might seem
a bit counter intuitive to have to pass that explicitly to a task like
`vaadinBuildFrontend`, which sole purpose usually is to build the
production stage.

Comment: Hi thanks for response I tried it but had no success. I've noticed one thing in build/resources/main/META-INF/VAADIN/build/config/flow-build-info.json there are CssImports: without any import. This is how it looks https://imgur.com/bqAGPst.